strict-mode unknown config directive: wsgi-file
У меня проект на Django. Появилась задача для подключения веб-сервера nginx. Настроил nginx.conf и default.conf, а также uwsgi.ini, чтобы корректно работала переадресация запросов от nginx в Django через uwsgi, однако при запуске uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini я получаю ошибку [strict-mode] unknown config directive: wsgi-file. Не понимаю почему, так как директива wsgi-file указывает на корректный путь. Версия последняя, устанавливал через homebrew.
nginx.conf
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    include /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    server_tokens off;
    include /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/default.conf; 
}

default.conf
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-CSRFToken $cookie_csrftoken;
    }
}

uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]

wsgi-file = website/wsgi.py  

strict = true  
socket = :8000  
protocol = http

master = true  

no-orphans = true   

die-on-term = true  

lazy-apps = true

processes = 4  

threads = 8   

enable-threads = true  

max-requests = 500

reload-on-rss = 1024

worker-reload-mercy = 60

harakiri = 60
harakiri-verbose = true

vacuum = true

post-buffering = 1048576

buffer-size = 65535

Traceback ошибки
(venv) nnhufg@localhost website % uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini 
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from uwsgi.ini
[strict-mode] unknown config directive: wsgi-file


Дополнила ответ, сделайте эту проверку.

Попробуйте запустить uWSGI с дополнительными параметрами:
uwsgi --ini website/uwsgi.ini --logto website/uwsgi.log


Попробуйте упростить конфигурацию, оставив только основные параметры:
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file = website/wsgi.py
master = true
processes = 4
socket = :8000

И поэтапно добавляйте параметры, чтоб локализовать проблему.
